# Apache POI encoding

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use Apache POI 3.13 to generate excel in cyrillic.

`HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Лист");`

I also tried:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(
    new String("Лист".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
);
```

But i get this error:

[image]

Comment: Might be the client you're using defaults to Windows 1252?

Comment: You probably also want to post the code you're using to populate the spreadsheet.

Comment: When you save your java program in your editor, what text encoding do you save it as? And when you compile the program, do you tell `javac` the same encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Use `XSSFSheet` instead of `HSSHSheet` like this.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Лист");
```

For this use `poi-ooxml 3.9`.
When saving the java file, there will be a alert message. Click `Save as UTF-8`.
Here is the image of alert message: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7NPe.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! good answer, you may improve your answer with minimal formatting (I've edited your post for that)